# How do I convert a string of comma values into a bulleted list in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm using a function that takes an array as the argument, but the problem is I have a string of comma values I need to use as the argument.

```
// comma values in a string
let comment = "Examples of things, Another thing, More things" 

// the bulletPoint function that takes an array.
func bulletPointList(strings: [String]) -> NSAttributedString {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 15
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 22
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 22
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 15)]

    let stringAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ]

    let string = strings.map({ "•\t\($0)" }).joined(separator: "\n")

    return NSAttributedString(string: string,
                              attributes: stringAttributes)
}
```

Should I just turn the comment string to an array first?

```
//The function looks like this called
label.numberOfLines = 0

label.attributedText = bulletPointList(strings: ["Examples of things", "Another thing", "More things"])
```

-Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you may use the following code to get string array.

```
let comment = "Examples of things, Another thing, More things"


let stringArray = comment.split(separator: ",").map{String($0)}
label.attributedText = bulletPointList(strings: stringArray)

//or

let stringArray1 = comment.components(separatedBy: ",")
label.attributedText = bulletPointList(strings: stringArray1)
```

Comment: I get an error of Cannot convert value of type '[String.SubSequence]' (aka 'Array<Substring>') to expected argument type '[String]'

Comment: The second one should work for [String], i.e.  `comment.components(separatedBy: ",")`; The first one, you can add map  function to make it work too.